# How to move a model using external C++ application and gazebo transport?

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-10

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Lets say I have a simple box loaded in gazebo world. How can I move this box using the gazebo transport client, and sample code somewhere, I don't see anything in examples that matches?

Second question is lets say I update position at 1Hz, can I also set the body rates, so gazebo smoothes the position in between position updates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24634/how-to-move-a-model-using-external-c++-application-and-gazebo-transport?/) by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I ended up just creating my own model plugin and created my own tcp interface using the gazebo/transport/Connection.hh . I didn't use full gazebo transport since I didn't want to make that a requirement for clients on the other side.

---

Originally posted by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) with karma: 45 on 2020-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0